# How to make smooth transitions between direction changes in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, google-maps-markers

I have the simple JS app which is moving marker on the map from the predefined GPS coords to given GPS position.

I would like to ask, how can i do smooth marker transition between direction changes? (Animation should give to user impression that marker is moving like the someone which is walks on the street, it means speed about 4 Km in hour)

I tried to find some working solution, but without the luck.

Here is the my JS fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/33uofo49/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Animated route</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  html, body, #map {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px
  }
 </style>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
 <script>

  var startDestination = [37.762836, -122.435011];
  var endDestination = [37.769452, -122.429186 ];
  var timeout = 1 * 1000; // seconds

  function initialize() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
     center: {lat: startDestination[0], lng: startDestination[1]},
     zoom: 100,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });
   
   getDirections(map);
  }

  function moveMarker(map, marker, latlng) {
   marker.setPosition(latlng);
   map.panTo(latlng);
  }

  function autoRefresh(map, pathCoords) {
   var i, route, marker;
   
   route = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    geodesic : true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: .5,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    editable: false,
    map:map
   });
   
   marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:map, icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"});

   for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {    
    setTimeout(function(coords) {
     route.getPath().push(coords);
     moveMarker(map, marker, coords);
    }, timeout * i, pathCoords[i]);
   }
  }
  
  function getDirections(map) {
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   
   var start = new google.maps.LatLng(startDestination[0], startDestination[1]);
   var end = new google.maps.LatLng(endDestination[0], endDestination[1]);

   var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
   };
   directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     autoRefresh(map, result.routes[0].overview_path);
    }
   });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the following solution:

- calculate the additional coordinates for the returned path from Directions service (see `interpolatePathBetween` function in the below example). The idea here is to provide the coordinates for route *calculated per every distance step*. For that purpose we will utilize functions from [`google.maps.geometry.spherical` namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical), in particular `interpolate` and `computeDistanceBetween` functions.
- once the path of the resulting directions contains enough coordinates, the `timeout` for `setTimeout` could be reduced

**Example**

```js
var startDestination = [37.762836, -122.435011];
var endDestination = [37.769452, -122.429186];

function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: startDestination[0], lng: startDestination[1] },
        zoom: 19,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    getDirections(map);
}

function moveMarker(map, marker, latlng) {
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
    map.panTo(latlng);
}

function autoRefresh(map, pathCoords) {
    var i, route, marker;

    route = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: .5,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        editable: false,
        map: map
    });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png" });

    
      
    interpolatePathBetween(pathCoords, 10);

    var timeout = 1 * 100; // seconds
    for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function (coords) {
            route.getPath().push(coords);
            moveMarker(map, marker, coords);
        }, timeout * i, pathCoords[i]);
    }
}


function interpolatePathBetween(path,step,curIndex){
    var curIndex = curIndex || 0;
    //verify path contains at least 2 coordinates
    if(path.length == 0 || path.length == 1) { 
        return;
    }
    step = Math.max(step,10); //ensure the step at least 10 meters 

    var start = path[curIndex];
    var end = path[curIndex+1];
    var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (start, end);
   
    if(dist > step) {
        var intCoord = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(start, end, .5);
        path.splice(curIndex+1, 0, intCoord);
        interpolatePathBetween(path,step,curIndex);
    }
   
    
    if(curIndex < path.length - 2) {
       interpolatePathBetween(path,step,curIndex + 1);
    }   

}

function getDirections(map) {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(startDestination[0], startDestination[1]);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(endDestination[0], endDestination[1]);

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            autoRefresh(map, result.routes[0].overview_path);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/noehga4u/)

Comment: Many thanks for Your reply. Your example is great, but it still does not like if  want to visualize someone is walking. New map view should be generated in shorter time intervals and distance jumps should be shorter. I tried to update Your example but i found issue that in some cases is marker moved about 20 meters at once. See:
https://jsfiddle.net/noehga4u/1/